# Azure API Management with Multiple Environments

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

My organization runs DEV, QA, UAT and Production environments.  Each one of the environments has a different set of backend endpoints.  The guidance provided by Microsoft is extremely vague on how to handle this situation.  I know that I can utilize properties to store the differences.  I can also get copies of all of the configuration utilizing the git repository.

My question is: How do I promote changes from DEV to QA and so on?  Each git repository is tied to the specific API Management instance.  I could manage more than one git repository, but I feel like that would be a lot of deleting and copying of files.  How have others solved this problem?  Or am I missing the boat in terms of how I should be managing this?

Comment: you do not move sources... you just change the cname's - though there are lots n lots of caveats to this - but should start the ball rolling

Comment: We are aware that the API lifecycle needs some love.  You can see from our [roadmap](https://trello.com/b/FAA147vS/azure-api-management-product-roadmap) that is something we are actively working to improve.  Erik's suggestion to use ARM templates is definitely worth looking into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into the new ARM templates feature to deploy API management.

The ARM template should contain all the parameters.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.apimanagement/api-management-create-all-resources

You still need a workflow to create the ARM templates for only the resources that are ready for the next environment.

For doing the GIT workflow, check this out: https://www.oppedijk.com/2017/02/04/api-management-dtap-lessons-learned.html
It describes how to work with GIT, you will need some 2 or 3 way merge tools. Also you need to keep the guids of all products the same for easy merging.